# Properly updating composer dependencies

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I'm currently using Laravel `5.1.11`, but looks like a feature I need is needed from `5.1.14`. I haven't used composer for too long, but is there a proper way I should go about upgrading? And are there any caveats I should watch out for in general?

Both my `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file have Laravel at `5.1.11` explicitly. Would I increment those to `5.1.14` and then run composer install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the version constraint in your `composer.json` file and then do an update to update the lock and installed packages.

Running `composer update` will update everything. This isn't always desirable on large projects requiring much regression testing.

You can whitelist packages by specifying them after the update.  `composer update my/package my-company/*`.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly run `composer update` which updates all Your dependencies to new versions.

Then normally add new dependency to the `composer.json` or run `composer require name/package`